# 2013 MacBook Pro Retina 13" vs MacBook Air 13"

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware-recommendation

I am considering buying a 13" MacBook. Please note that this would be my first Apple device. The two the options that I am considering are:

1. MacBook Air, 2013, 13", 128GB SSD, 1.4GHz dual-core Intel Core i5, 4GB DDR3
2. MacBook Pro with Retina display, 2013, 13", 128GB SDD, 2.4GHz dual-core Intel Core i5, 4GB DDR3

There are some issues that I am concerned about:

- Performance
- Is the 128GB enough? (How much would the OS take up of this?)
- The MacBook Pro seems to be quite tough. Does it also apply to the Air?
- I am also interested in Windows alternatives... I am looking for "13 ultrabooks with long battery life + SSD and decent computing power. Could you recommend any?
- In general, what are the pros and cons of MacBook Air vs. Windows ultrabooks?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The only downsides of a MBP over an Air is price and battery life. Although pros have already excellent battery life (and usually better than Windows running alternatives). If price is not an issue a rMBP would be a better choice. OSX takes only a few gigs, if you do not plan to install games/manipulate video or stock tons of photos 128G should be enough, but you can judge that from your current drive usage. Comparing Windows ultrabooks to to MBAs is outside the scope of this forum I think.

Comment: Bunches of problems with this post. 1. Discussion oriented 2. Too many questions 3. Hardware shopping 4. Duplicate of other questions that explain _how_ to weigh differences as opposed to comparing two current machines ["Who would win in a fight, gorilla vs shark"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) If anyone wants to save this for editing / reopening, let's chat on [meta] on how to fix it if one big edit isn't sufficient to get a reopen.

Answer (score 0):

My first Mac is a MacBook Air.

It is now 18 months old -still a baby :)

I love it:

First it is slim and very light- important for me.

I do have the 256 Gig SSD, and after a Year it is filled up with Photos and Movies consuming 110 Gig.

I travel a lot and love the intelligent WiFi, it always finds me a connection.

The Display is sufficient for my uses, and the Thunderbolt is a killer.
I just connect my TV using a HDMI cable and have huge screen.

Speed is sufficient for what I do and it has not been bottle neck so far, and the 4 Gig RAM seem to do the work.

Since my laptops last about 3 Years, I do not mind not been able to do upgrades.

The Mavericks takes 5.3 Gig, so with all the Media stuff I recommend the 256 Gig SSD.

My MBA is tough (so far taken anything I trow at it), but have not drooped it to find out. The fans are very quiet.